# Sniff packages between 2 devices via usb

Tags: usb, package, reverse-engineering, packet-sniffers, sniffing

I need to sniff data packages exchanged between a device And a PC connected via usb (Micro usb). My goal is To find out how The device "talk" with The original software so i Can program a new one with more functions And more languages translations. Since i'm a bit confused on how to accomplish it, i need some suggestions And Tips. Is this Even possible?  From where i should start?

Answer (score 0):

Yes not only its possible, its always used by engineers all over the world who work on USB. Its called USB packet analyzer.
Connect the device to the analyzer and the analyzer to the PC.

You will also get a software from the analyzer manufacturer to capture the packets.

But these hardware are costly. The famous analyzers are Ellysis, LeCroy, etc.

http://www.ellisys.com/products/usbex200/

http://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle-usb480/ - This is cheap and great for personal development

I use Lecroy in my company but thats really costly for personal projects.